# Android: ViewFlipper in RecyclerView Adapter?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have `CardViews` in a `RecyclerView` that show the user an amount of time remaining until an expiration date.  I'd like to add a `ViewFlipper` within the `CardView` that flips column headings for the output depending on how much time remains.

For example, when there are more than 2 years left the headings on the `CardView` would look like this:

[image]

When the time remaining is less than 2 years the column headings would flip to this:

[image]

Sample ViewFlipper code for the RecyclerView Adapter file:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ContactHolder holder, int position) {
    final Contact contact = contactList.get(position);

    long timer = date.getTime();
    Date today = new Date();
    final long currentTime = today.getTime();
    long diff = timer - currentTime;

    ViewFlipper viewFlipperVH;
    viewFlipperVH = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper2);

    if(diff >= 2) {
        viewFlipperVH.setDisplayedChild(viewFlipperVH.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.diff2years)));
    } else {
        viewFlipperVH.setDisplayedChild(viewFlipperVH.indexOfChild(findViewById(R.id.diff1year)));
    }
```

I tried adding the code in onCreateViewHolder also but Android Studio states "Cannot resolve method 'findViewById(int)'"

What am I missing here?  Can ViewFlipper only be used in an Activity file?

layout file:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="right"  >

    <ViewFlipper
        android:id="@+id/viewFlipper2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/diff2years"
            android:id="@+id/diff2years"  />

        <include layout="@layout/diff1year"
            android:id="@+id/diff1year"  />

    </ViewFlipper>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Using `ViewFlipper` for this seems like a little overkill. Couldn't you just change the text and text color as needed?

Comment: Sure, can you provide a quick example to get me going in the right direction?

Comment: Well, there wouldn't be much to show. You'd just replace your `ViewFlipper` with a `TextView`, and `if(diff >= 2)`, then you'd `setText("Years")` and `setTextColor(Color.RED)`, otherwise `"Year"` and `BLUE`.

Comment: Ok, been definitely staring at this too long.  Using setText and some simple if else statements should be good.  I appreciate the reply, cheers.

Comment: Sure thing. Btw, you shouldn't need to be calling `findViewById()` in `onBindViewHolder()`, and that's not quite right anyway. You should be finding all of the `View`s in `onCreateViewHolder()`, and calling `findViewById()` on the `View` you're inflating. That might be why Android Studio was complaining.

Comment: Yes, I now understand that...I have a ContactHolder that extends the ViewHolder and that is where all of the findViewByIds are located for the itemView and the onCreateViewHolder inflates the CardView layout.  I will use the if statement and setText in the onBindViewHolder.